# Spark data manipulation with wholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have 20k compressed files of ~2MB to manipulate in spark. My initial idea was to use `wholeTextFiles()` so that I get filename - > content tuples. This is useful because I need to maintain this kind of pairing (because the processing is done on a per file basis, with each file representing a minute of gathered data). However, whenever I need to map/filter/etc the data and to maintain this filename - > association, the code gets ugly (and perhaps not efficient?) i.e.

```
Data.map(lambda (x,y) : (x, y.changeSomehow))
```

The data itself, so the content of each file, would be nice to read as a separate RDD because it contains 10k's of lines of data; however, one cannot have an rdd of rdds (as far as i know).

Is there any way to ease the process? Any workaround that would basically allow me to use the content of each file as an rdd, hence allowing me to do `rdd.map(lambda x: change(x))` without the ugly keeping track of filename (and usage of list comprehensions instead of transformations) ?

The goal of course is to also maintain the distributed approach and to not inhibit it in any way.

The last step of the processing will be to gather together everything through a reduce.

More background: trying to identify (near) ship collisions on a per minute basis, then plot their path

Comment: If you need speed, I suggest scala. Python is about 10x slower, on one side because python is just inherently slower, and on the other side because it has to ship the data from the jvm to python

Comment: @Reactormonk I would like to do that. However, I must use a python script to decode virtually every line inside the files. More precisely, I'm talking about AIS messages for which i only found code in python (too complex to write my own given the time I have). If you know a workaround, do tell

Comment: https://github.com/dma-ais/AisLib ?

Comment: Looks like 2.5x is more accurate. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/24/recent-performance-improvements-in-apache-spark-sql-python-dataframes-and-more.html / http://emptypipes.org/2015/01/17/python-vs-scala-vs-spark/ So only half an order of magnitude instead of a full one. Even less with pypy.

Comment: @Reactormonk Ah I completely forgot Java in Scala is very easy because of the JVM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have normal `map` functions (o1->o2), you can use [mapValues](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapValues) function. You've got also flatMap (o1 -> Collection()) function: flatMapValues.

It will keep Key (in your case - file name) and change only values.

For example:

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles (...)
# RDD of i.e. one pair, /test/file.txt -> Apache Spark
rddMapped = rdd.mapValues (lambda x: veryImportantDataOf(x))
# result: one pair: /test/file.txt -> Spark
```

Using reduceByKey you can reduce results

Comment: That's already an improvement, thanks! So some of my lines now look like `data.mapValues(lambda x: [list comprehension]) `,where list contains every line in the file. It would be awesome though if the x was an rdd of its own, instead of a list, in terms of efficiency and readability. Do you agree, and maybe have an idea how to do so?

Comment: Value of the key-pair RDD cannot be a RDD. It can be any serializable data structure, i.e. you can create case class `DocumentContent`. RDD is something like logical plan of transformation of the data, it's not only a collection. Driver must construct a chain of invocations to proceed with RDD action, embedded RDD will cause many problems and that's why RDD of RDD is not allowed